# Can't install H5PY - HDF5.dll dependency not found

Tags: python

I'm trying to install a library which relies on h5py.
However, when I try to install it I get this error:

> Collecting h5py   Using cached h5py-3.1.0.tar.gz (371 kB)   Installing build dependencies ... done   Getting requirements to build wheel ... done   Installing backend dependencies ... done
> Preparing wheel metadata ... done Collecting markdown>=2.6.8   Using cached Markdown-3.3.3-py3-none-any.whl (96 kB) Collecting werkzeug>=0.11.10   Using cached Werkzeug-1.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (298 kB) Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: setuptools in c:\users\user\desktop\projects\python\mlagents\venv\lib\site-packages (from protobuf>=3.6.1-
> tensorflow==1.12.0) (50.3.2) Using legacy 'setup.py install' for termcolor, since package 'wheel' is not installed. Building wheels for collected packages: h5py   Building wheel for h5py (PEP 517) ... error ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:    command: 'c:\users\user\desktop\projects\python\mlagents\venv\scripts\python.exe' 'c:\users\user\desktop\projects\python\mlagents\venv\lib\site-packages \pip_vendor\pep517_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpf62jt8ch'
> cwd: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7diegpjl\h5py   Complete output (70 lines):   running bdist_wheel   running build   running build_py   creating build   creating build\lib.win32-3.8   creating build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py   copying h5py\h5py_warnings.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py   copying h5py\ipy_completer.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py   copying h5py\version.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py   copying h5py_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py   creating build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py_hl   copying h5py_hl\attrs.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py_hl   copying h5py_hl\base.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py_hl   copying h5py_hl\compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py_hl   copying h5py_hl\dataset.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py_hl   copying h5py_hl\datatype.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py_hl   copying h5py_hl\dims.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py_hl   copying h5py_hl\files.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py_hl   copying h5py_hl\filters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py_hl   copying h5py_hl\group.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py_hl   copying h5py_hl\selections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py_hl   copying h5py_hl\selections2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py_hl   copying h5py_hl\vds.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py_hl   copying h5py_hl_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py_hl   creating build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests   copying h5py\tests\common.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests   copying h5py\tests\conftest.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests   copying h5py\tests\test_attribute_create.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests  copying h5py\tests\test_attrs.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests   copying h5py\tests\test_attrs_data.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests   copying h5py\tests\test_base.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests   copying h5py\tests\test_big_endian_file.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests   copying h5py\tests\test_completions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests   copying h5py\tests\test_dataset.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests   copying h5py\tests\test_dataset_getitem.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests   copying h5py\tests\test_dataset_swmr.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests   copying h5py\tests\test_datatype.py
> -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests   copying h5py\tests\test_dimension_scales.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests  copying h5py\tests\test_dims_dimensionproxy.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests   copying h5py\tests\test_dtype.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests   copying h5py\tests\test_errors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests   copying h5py\tests\test_file.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests   copying h5py\tests\test_file2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests   copying h5py\tests\test_file_image.py
> -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests   copying h5py\tests\test_filters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests   copying h5py\tests\test_group.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests   copying h5py\tests\test_h5.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests   copying h5py\tests\test_h5d_direct_chunk.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests  copying h5py\tests\test_h5f.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests   copying h5py\tests\test_h5p.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests   copying h5py\tests\test_h5pl.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests   copying h5py\tests\test_h5t.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests   copying h5py\tests\test_objects.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests   copying h5py\tests\test_selections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests   copying h5py\tests\test_slicing.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests   copying h5py\tests_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests   creating build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\data_files   copying h5py\tests\data_files_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\data_files   creating build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\test_vds   copying h5py\tests\test_vds\test_highlevel_vds.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\test_vds   copying h5py\tests\test_vds\test_lowlevel_vds.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\test_vds   copying h5py\tests\test_vds\test_virtual_source.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\test_vds   copying h5py\tests\test_vds_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\test_vds   copying h5py\tests\data_files\vlen_string_dset.h5 -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\data_files   copying h5py\tests\data_files\vlen_string_dset_utc.h5 -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\data_files   copying h5py\tests\data_files\vlen_string_s390x.h5 -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\data_files   running build_ext   Loading library to get version: hdf5.dll   error: Unable to load dependency HDF5, make sure HDF5 is installed properly   error: Could not find module 'hdf5.dll'. Try using the full path with constructor syntax.

---

ERROR: Failed building wheel for h5py Failed to build h5py ERROR: Could not build wheels for h5py which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

I realize from that that i"m missing HDF5 however I could not find a proper way to install it.
And even if I do, I have no idea where h5py wants its dll to be in order to be read.

**Edit**
I am using Python 3.8.0
And if someone wonders what library I tried to install is tensorflow.

```
pip install tensorflow
```

is not working for me so I used the direct wheel file for version 1.14.0

Appreciating your help :)

Answer (score 11):

I'm using Python 3.9 on Apple Silicon and faced with the same error.
I fixed it by the following procedures:

1. `brew install hdf5`
2. `git clone https://github.com/h5py/h5py`
3. Open `setup_configure.py` and modify [this line](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/blob/master/setup_configure.py#L201):

```
- default_path = 'libhdf5.dylib'
+ default_path = '/opt/homebrew/lib/libhdf5.dylib'
```

4. `H5PY_SETUP_REQUIRES=0 python3 setup.py build`
5. `python3 -m pip install . --no-build-isolation`

Comment: It worked like a charm.  I looked up H5PY_SETUP_REQUIRES=0, but could not find a good description of its function.  Could you describe briefly ?

Comment: @akh22 It's for skipping `setup_require` (see this line: https://github.com/h5py/h5py/blob/master/setup.py#L63). By default `setup.py` installs external modules such as numpy, which also has some installation troubles with M1. To avoid installing them, set `H5PY_SETUP_REQUIRES=0` and execute `pip install` with `--no-build-isolation` .

Comment: This is actually configurable through the `HDF5_DIR` env var (https://github.com/h5py/h5py/blob/master/setup_configure.py#L89), so no need to clone the repo and edit the default value. Setting the env var `HDF5_DIR="$(brew --prefix hdf5)"` does the trick.

Comment: no special editing required for me, I just had to specify the include and library paths on the cmdline, like this: 

`python3 setup.py build build_ext --include-dirs=/opt/homebrew/include --library-dirs=/opt/homebrew/lib`

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the major update (python 3.9) has so many bugs. I tried to install opencv module in python and it prompts the same error, you have two options;

1. you can download the older version of python like python 3.8/7, which can support H5PY.
2. Be patient and wait for python to fix all the bugs, it will be all good at mid december or earlier.

hope it helped ya! :)

Comment: Wait python 3.9 sitll affects me even though I am using 3.8?
If so then damn that kinda sucks(Tho the way you say it in solution 1 imples it doesn't..)
I am already using python 3.8.0 as I mentioned in the question, I removed python 3.9 before after I realized it's full of bugs, but with 3.8 it doesn't work either

Comment: @1Mangomaster1 just a suggestion, don't use phrases like "damn that kinda sucks". It isn't exactly wrong or anything... it is just picked up by some systems to check for inappropriate behaviour. Your comment wasn't inappropriate but it is better to not attract unwanted attention :)

Comment: You're right.. I'm sorry.
I just kinda frustrates me because it keeps me stuck until this issue will be resolved.
Although Python 3.8.0 should've been old enough for this problem to be resolved...
I just can't understand why the error still persists

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade to older versions of python until you can install keras(i guess this is where you are facing the problem). Went from python 3.8 to 3.7 and at last to 3.6.8, where i did not face any errors like the previous versions. Nothing to worry as this python version supports almost every library as the latest versions.

Answer (score -1):

This is strange because I've seen people install tensorflow on versions newer than Python 3.8.. but I found somewhere that H5PY is not compatible with python 3.8
and that I need to downgrade...

However, I think it's because older versions of tensorflow do work for me, but what I do requires at least 1.14.0...

I'll try to downgrade python more(to python 3.7.) and update you on it

**EDIT**

It's working. I am using Python 3.7.2 and everything works perfectly!
I didn't even have to get the wheel file for tensorflow I could just do pip install tensorflow normally.

Thanks for everyone who commented :)